# How can I Display A Navbar Logo?

Tags: html, navbar

After about 6 months of online courses, I am finally starting to build my app MVP.
I am working on the layout, using Windows 10 and Meteor 2.7.3. I think I have most packages installed so far, like **iron:router**, jquery, twbs:bootstrap, accounts-ui and others...

I have tried my local C:/ drive path, multiple codes all over, including here on similar questions, but my logo will not appear at all!

I have also tried to use a logo template, and nested it into the header template. I have tried to access the logo from my Google Drive. Nothing shows up!

- Logo Template (I have removed the template tags)

```html
    <div class="m-0 order-0 order-md-1 position-absolute main-     logo">
      <img src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/11dNYA54BTlirUPA5Yy02kgUh1_kg-xlu/view" class="rounded-circle" width="55px" >
    </div>
```

- Header Template (I have removed the template tags)

```html
  <header>
    <head>

<html lang="en">

  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>MoAB Group</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.2/css/all.css" />

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.markuptag.com/bootstrap/5/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

</html>
</head>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
        <div class="container">
        
          <div class="m-0 order-0 order-md-1 position-absolute main-logo">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href='/home'><!--{{> logo}}--><img src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/11dNYA54BTlirUPA5Yy02kgUh1_kg-xlu/view" class="rounded-circle" width="55px" ></a>
          </div>
        
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
        
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="/home">
                Home
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="/about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link active dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Projects
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/ideatoprod">Idea to Product</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/prototyping">Prototyping</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/mvppitch">MVP Pitch</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          
          
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="/funding">
                Funding
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="/news">
                News
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="/blog">
                Blog
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="/admin">
                Admin
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="/contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <div class="d-flex">
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="btn btn-light dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Services
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Product Development</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Prototyping</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">MVP Building</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light d-table           my-5 mx-auto" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-                 target="#ModalForm">
          {{> loginButtons}}
        </button>
      </div>
      </nav>
```

Comment: Are you certain that the logo is shared for viewing by that link w/o permissions or signing into Google Drive?  Are you trying to host your project on a local webserver, or just accessing it from the filesystem?  Also, have you validated that it is _possible_ to use Google Drive to host static web content?  Seems like something Google might try to prevent if it isn't explicitly allowed or intended for that usage...

Comment: @AlexanderNied, thank you for replying. I first tried my local server (my laptop drive), it works when I use a simple html project without Meteor. But once I set everything up on Meteor, with the routing services, nothing works. I just used this link: https://www.facebook.com/MoABGroup/photos/a.113668233604663/405053977799419/ it did not work either. But this one link from a demo navbar works: https://bootstrapious.com/i/snippets/sn-nav-logo/logo.png. So if I understand correctly, I must upload my images online where there's no need for permissions. BTW, I did validate the file on Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need eventually to run a webserver like apache or nginx to serve your website, even just for development on your own machine.

In this case, a relative path should work, say you put index.html and your image navbar-logo.png in the same directory, and just open index.html on your filesystem:

```html
    <div class="m-0 order-0 order-md-1 position-absolute main-     logo">
      <img src="navbar-logo.png" class="rounded-circle" width="55px" >
   </div>
```

Alexander Nied is correct, google would prevent you from using drive to host web content.

Comment: thanks, I think I just figured it out by using my facebook page logo link, it works. I just need to customise the shape, make it round instead of square : https://scontent.fabj3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.30808-6/245148391_405053971132753_8614564847337166699_n.png?_nc_cat=109&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=09cbfe&_nc_ohc=ISp94hRQhUAAX-jqoZb&_nc_ht=scontent.fabj3-1.fna&oh=00_AT_BwdlJZ0ieWp-YOY2f3J84G49FIypktfgifMvEwhkS0A&oe=62C34402